# RecyclerView + SGLM layout implementation

Tags: android, baseadapter, material-design, android-recyclerview, staggered-gridview

So..

I'm developing an android app that requires a StaggeredGridLayoutManager and the new RecyclerView for displaying different boxes of content across the screen.

I have already made some tests ( see imgur screenshot below ) and i get the general idea of how to use this. I've made some other apps before, but none as big a challenge as this one.

The project i'm doing requires some advance knowledge in many fields and i wanted to ask some pointers to the right approach of doing this.

The basic requirements are:

1. *Different view containers for each cell, with different sizes, and different content. ( so far im only able to use a single inflated view). The different box sizes you see below i just made with a textview with the same color as the layout background and different String size so the height changes, but it is the same view.
2. *Google Inbox like animation when clicking a view ( the animation when opening an email ) and push the other views in the SGLM away
3. *Displaying the info, pulled from a backend, on the 'opened' view (with the animation above)

I know this sounds like a vague question but basically, i want to know if there is any implementation of the point made above. I know Material Design brings many many animations and some other touches, so is there any thing like i stated in there?

Should i use fragments in there instead of regular views?

Thanks

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oWtcg.png

Answer (score 0):

Fragments are too heavy. You should consider using [RecyclerView.Adapter#getItemViewType(int)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#getItemViewType%28int%29) method. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26245463/759007) you can find how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can find out here the github project:

[Picasso/Glide-RecyclerView-StaggeredGridLayoutManager](https://github.com/yuvaraj119/Picasso-RecyclerView-StaggeredGridLayoutManager)